# How to sort Collection in this specific way?

Tags: java, sorting

I had a final exam of OOP 1 (**we use Java**) at university back in december, and I did not pass. The thing was that I had to sort something in a kinda-specific way, and I can't figure out how to properly implement this. I will translate just a part of the exercise (I will do it with help of Google Translate):

*"... John loves natural numbers, and he likes mostly the even numbers other than the odd numbers. Inside each subset, he prefers the smallest ones."*

[HERE is the original exercise (**in spanish**)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKMzY.jpg)

OK, so, I have to do this inside a class called Natural, and I have to be able to sort it in that custom way (described above). This is which I am not able to do. I know (a teacher told me after the exam) that I had to implement `Comparable<T>`.

(I know this part) After that, I had to instantiate a LinkedList<*Natural*>, read numbers from a file, sort them and put them (having being sorted) into another file.

Sorry if this is confusing, my English is really bad.

This is what I have in my `class Natural`:

```
public class Natural implements Comparable<Natural> {

    public Integer numNatural;

    public int compareTo(Natural otroNatural) {

        Integer numNatural2 = ((Natural) otroNatural).numNatural;

        if (this.numNatural > numNatural2) return 1;
        else if (this.numNatural < numNatural2) return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
```

How can I make my program to understand that I need to put first the even numbers, and inside the even numbers, the smallest ones? After that, the smallest odd numbers should be sorted also.

Comment: You have to evaluate inside your method if the number inserted is prime using the modulo operator. Then you add it to another collection, then finally sort your collection and return it. You can set different methods to handle that and call them inside your compareTo method.

Comment: @Archie you probably meant checking for even or odd, instead of prime.

Comment: I  think you meant you did not "pass the exam" . "Approve the exam" means something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several cases, and it would help to consider these individually.

1. even number vs even number
2. even number vs odd number
3. odd number vs even number
4. odd number vs odd number

For the second and third case you can already return 1/-1 as you know the answer without further logic. For the other two cases you need to compare as you've already shown in your answer.

Comment: Actually just two cases here: either `a` and `b` are both even or both odd – then just compare them; or one of them is even and second is odd, or _vice versa_ – then the even one goes first.

Comment: if a is even && b is odd
   return -1;
if a is odd && b is even
   return 1;
return a < b ? -1: 1;

Comment: `return a % 2 == b % 2 ? a.compareTo(b) : a % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1;` ;)